# how to develop/test angular in spring boot without building it

Tags: spring-boot

Maybe someone call help me to find a solution.

I have an angular app in a different folder of my git project.
Normally i use ng serve and open the frontend on its dedicated port.
I start the spring boot app on its own port and set a CORS filter to allow it.

However now that we are testing OAUTH i would like the frontend to be served be backend.
My problem is that ng serve is in memory and i dont know what would be the best option to include them into the backend.

I have tried to build them into the backend and then rebuild with mavent but that takes way to long for every small change on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a proxy which forwards requests to APIs or UI based on the Path. Something like

```
http://localhost:8888/api ---> [Proxy Server (localhost:8888)] ---> Spring Boot API (http://localhost:8080

http://proxy-domain.com:proxy-port/ui ---> [Proxy Server (localhost:8888)] ----> Angular App (http://localhost:4200)
```

For the proxy server, you can use free tools like ***Fiddler*** and have a rule there to route based on the URL patters (`/api` or `/ui`)